# TypeError: bott() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given even with self

Tags: python, kivy

I have `self` in all functions, but I still get the error in the title. I don't know what to try, any help?

Here is the code:

```
class layy(App):
    global t
    t = TextInput(hint_text='insert text')

    global c
    global s
    s = TextInput(hint_text='insert time till begin')
    c = TextInput(hint_text='insert amount')

    def bott(self):

        am = c.text
        if (am == ""):
            am = '0'
        l = int(am)

        pm = c.text
        if (pm == ""):
            pm = '0'
        o = int(pm)
        base = 0

        time.sleep(o)
        while (base < l):
            pyautogui.typewrite(t)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            base = base + 1

    def build(self):

        b = Button(text = 'Start Spam')
        b.bind(on_press = self.bott)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        sublay1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        sublay2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        sublay3 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        layout.add_widget(sublay1)
        sublay1.add_widget(t)

        layout.add_widget(sublay2)
        sublay2.add_widget(s)
        sublay2.add_widget(c)

        layout.add_widget(sublay3)
        sublay3.add_widget(b)

        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    layy().run()
```

If any more information is needed, this is supposed to repeat sending the desired text as many times as I need.  If anyone knows what to do, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy event handlers can take any number of parameters. I haven't found a good source for what parameters are given for each callback type, but the [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#module-kivy.uix.button) has an example that uses `on_press` and it receives the button instance being pressed. That's the second mystery parameter the error references. Just add it to your method

```
def bott(self, instance):
    do the things...
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry if it was simple, i'm new to python

Comment: The main thing to know is that all event callbacks pass as an argument the instance of the class from which the event was dispatched. Other arguments should be documented with specific event types.

Comment: @inclement - Thanks, I couldn't find a definitive list of events so didn't know if 0 args was an option.